# xpages address book lookup

Tags: xpages, lotus-formula

I created an `edit box` which bends on a `Names` fields inside my form.

I checked the `Enable Type Ahead` and at the Suggestions I added:

```
var db = new Array(@DbName()[0], "names.nsf");
@DbColumn(db, "($VIMPeopleAndGroups)", 2)
```

but it doesn't works for me. Is the view name correct typed?

My application works both on Notes client and web-browser.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your is code is correct but I guess your current user Anonymous (?) is not allowed to access names.nsf.

Log in as a named user on browser and then it should work.

You can shorten your code to:

```
@DbColumn("names.nsf", "($VIMPeopleAndGroups)", 2)
```

if you don't use XPiNC as the code is running on server and therefore you don't need to specify a server name as parameter.

But, consider to use `xe:namePicker` with `xe:dominoNABNamePicker` instead.

Comment: I am log in, I even have a computed field which displays my name: @Name("[CN]", session.getEffectiveUserName())

Comment: Insert a Multiline Edit Box into your page with the code for "value" to see if it works in general.

Comment: no, for "value": `<xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea1">
  <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn("names.nsf", "($VIMPeopleAndGroups)", 2)}]]></xp:this.value>
 </xp:inputTextarea>`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The <Value> from the Properties.

Comment: Bear in mind that omitting the server name will fail if the application is ever used via XPiNC and "Run server-based XPages apps directly on server" is not ticked. As a result, I generally advise developers to always include the server in @DbLookup/@DbColumn

Comment: I added the code at the value property: now it is strange, the multiple edit box is not shown, it is 'invisible'

Comment: that means the code failed - it is not editable because we set value direct and don't use an editable field or scope variable.

Comment: @Paul Stephen Withers: thanks for valuable comment, I updated my answer.

Comment: My fault to specify just now: My app goes on Client notes as well.

Comment: Where are you testing right now? In browser or XPiNC?

Comment: I'm testing it in Browser

Comment: I'd suggest your alternatives as the right way to do it. @DbColumn does not factor in if you have multiple NABs, or condensed NABs, etc.

Comment: Please check the "Maximum Internet name and password" level in tab "Advanced" in names.nsf's ACL - it has to be at least "Reader"

Comment: I have checked and it is <Editor>

Comment: Please open the view "($VIMPeopleAndGroups)" in Notes client that we sure that it is calculated - I had an issue with that recently.

Comment: I will have to talk with our Admin. By the way, initially I was looking to create a field similar to the Names field from classic Notes. My goal is to send a link ( the doc. link ) via a button inside the doc. to a person, whose name is inside this editbox/name field

Comment: Then you really should use `xe:dominoNABNamePicker`. Look at Extension Library Example database at Domino_Pickers.xsp - there you get it "out of the box".

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I will speak with our Admin, I'm curious with the ($VIMPeopleAndGroups) view and if it is recalculating,

Comment: You can test it yourself - just open names.nsf in Notes Client and then press SHIFT + STRG clicking on menu "View / Go To..." - it will show you all hidden views to select from.